# insert retrive data in insert retrieve data array codeigniter model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Insert and retrive data with an array using codeigniter model.

The model:

```
 function abc {

   $tomorrow_date=$this->input->post('datee');
   $id=$this->input->post('id');

   $this -> db -> select('name,phone,address,age'); 
   $this -> db -> from('user_reg');
   $this -> db -> where('patient_id',$id);
   $this -> db -> where('date',$tomorrow_date);
   $query = $this -> db -> get();

   if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
   {
   $row = $query->row(); 

   }
```

I want to insert it such as:

```
    $data = array( 
                 'date'=>$tomorrow_date,
                 'name'=>$name,
                 'phone'=>$phone,
                 'address'=>$address,
                 'age'=>$age,
                 'patient_id'=>id,



                 );
  $this->db->insert('user_info',$data);
 }
```

How can I insert the data?

Answer (score 0):

```
function abc {

   $tomorrow_date=$this->input->post('datee');
   $id=$this->input->post('id');

   $this -> db -> select('name,phone,address,age'); 
   $this -> db -> from('user_reg');
   $this -> db -> where('patient_id',$id);
   $this -> db -> where('date',$tomorrow_date);
   $query = $this -> db -> get()->row_array();

   if ($query->num_rows() > 0){

         $data = array( 
             'date'=>$tomorrow_date,
             'name'=>$query['name'],
             'phone'=>$query['phone'],
             'address'=>$query['address'],
             'age'=>$query['age'],
             'patient_id'=>$id
        );
     }

   $this->db->insert('user_info',$data);
}
```